# How would I detect the amount of consecutive times a character appears in string and if it reaches a certain value print to the command

Tags: python

I am looking through a very large block of data in a text that looks like this:

```
 >|title| information
asdfsdfsdfsasdfsdfsdfsasdfsdfsdfs
asseefadfefeeedddeeeedddasdfsdf
asdfsdfsdfsasdfsdfsdfsasdfsdfsdfs
asseefadfefeeedddeeeedddasdfsdf
>|title| information
asseefadfefeeedddedeedddasdfsdf
asseefadfeasdfsdfsdfsasdfsdfdfsdf
asdfsdfsdfsasdfsdfsdfsasdfsdfsdfs
asseefadfefeeedddedeedddasdfsdf
```

What I want to do is to find the lines of the data where e/d are repeated 10 or more times in a row. The script would check the data and print out the numbers of the lines where e/d being repeated were detected. So in the case above it would print out 3 5 7 10.

What I've done so far makes no sense to me and I feel that there is a simple solution I am just doing terribly finding.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use `regex` for pattern detection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Regex. The pattern is pretty simple, first we define non capturing group, then inside that group, we match d or e 10 times in row, and thats about it.

```
    import re
    lines = [
      "asdfsdfsdfsasdfsdfsdfsasdfsdfsdfs",
      "asseefadfefeeedddeeeedddasdfsdf",
      "asdfsdfsdfsasdfsdfsdfsasdfsdfsdfs",
      "asseefadfefeeedddeeeedddasdfsdf",
      "asseefadfefeeedddedeedddasdfsdf",
      "asseefadfeasdfsdfsdfsasdfsdfdfsdf",
      "asdfsdfsdfsasdfsdfsdfsasdfsdfsdfs",
      "asseefadfefeeedddedeedddasdfsdf"
    ]
    i = 1
    for line in lines:
      reg = re.search(r"(?:[d|e]{10})", line)
      if reg:
        print(f"Line {i} matched!")
      i+=1
```

[Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xyaPkt/1)

Edit:
As @fsimonjetz mentioned, the group is unnecessary, and it has edgecase where it matches |.

```
import re
    lines = [
      "asdfsdfsdfsasdfsdfsdfsasdfsdfsdfs",
      "asseefadfefeeedddeeeedddasdfsdf",
      "asdfsdfsdfsasdfsdfsdfsasdfsdfsdfs",
      "asseefadfefeeedddeeeedddasdfsdf",
      "asseefadfefeeedddedeedddasdfsdf",
      "asseefadfeasdfsdfsdfsasdfsdfdfsdf",
      "asdfsdfsdfsasdfsdfsdfsasdfsdfsdfs",
      "asseefadfefeeedddedeedddasdfsdf"
    ]
    i = 1
    for line in lines:
      reg = re.search(r"[de]{10}", line)
      if reg:
        print(f"Line {i} matched!")
      i+=1
```

[Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/1RcmBJ/1)

Comment: is there a less then/equal to in regex by any chances?

Comment: You can set how many matches you want either of d or e by {1, 10}, which means atleast 1 match but no more than 10. If that is what you mean ?
`reg = re.search(r"(?:[d|e]{1,10})", line)`

Comment: Upvoted. However, note that the pipe symbol within `[]` matches literal `|` and the non-capturing group is not really needed, so `r"[de]{10}"` would do.